# Spring add references to different projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, project

Newbie question: I have different projects that im doing in STS, all opened. For example i have myproject_mvc and myproject_datamodel.

In myproject_mvc are the views and controllers. 
In myproject_datamodel are the class of the Model like: Person, Car, etc.

the project_datamodel is used in other projects too. So i want to add a reference and use it like if that class where in myproject_mvc.

I added doing right click over myproject_mvc Build Path/Configure Build Path/Projects and i added the porject there, but when i run the application i recieve this error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: solvian_datamodel/Vehicle

Maybe i have to register that dependency in pom.xml or other file that i dont know.

Comment: This question is related to the tools you're using to compile your projects. What IDE and build tools are you using? (Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellj, maven, gradle, ant?)

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo, im using Eclipse, STS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Web Deployment Assembly in STS.

Try following:

1. Go to myproject_mvc's properties -> Deployment Assembly.
2. Click Add button.
3. Add dependency projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I resolve the issue. I added the reference and also added in POM.XML and then because of the Bean creation i added the bean information at servlet-context.xml file. So i had to make 3 task.